# Problem with solving the recurrence relation $a_n=a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}+30$ for $n\geq2$, $a_0=0$, $a_1=-10$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My task:
$a_n=a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}+30$ for $n\geq2$,  $a_0=0$, $a_1=-10$

My solution
$x^{2}-x-6$

$\Delta=25$

$x1=-2 $

$x2=3$

So I am gonna use following formula:
$a_n=ar^{n}+br^{n}$

$a_n=a*(-2)^{n}+b*3^{n}$

$a_0=0=a+b$

$a_1=-10=-2a+3b$

$b=-2$

$a=2$

$a_n=2*(-2)^{n}-2*3^{n}+30$

I calculate $a_2$

$a_2=-10+0+30=20$

Which is correct with above formula

$a_2=2*(-2)^{2}-2*3^{2}+30=20$

but for $a_3$ and above results are not matching, am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The $+30$ is the problem. Find $c$ such that $b_n:=a_n+c\implies b_n=b_{n-1}+6b_{n-2}$, then use your usual techniques.

Edit to add detail:

$$b_n=b_{n-1}-c+6(b_{n-2}-c)+30+c=b_{n-1}+6b_{n-2}+30-6c$$ Set $c=5$ so $$b_n=b_{n-1}+6b_{n-2}\implies\exists a,\,b:\,b_n=a(-2)^n+b3^n.$$From $b_0=5,\,b_1=-5$, you can find $a,\,b$. Then $a_n=b_n-5$.

Comment: I don't really get it, could you show me how its supposed to look in my case?
That's the best way for me to understand it.

Comment: @Gorosso See my edit.

Comment: Where does c=5 come from? Also what I am supposed to do with $a_n=b_n-5$?

Comment: @Gorosso The technique you used originally only works when there isn't a constant in the recursion relation, so I chose $c$ to delete it. Once you have a formula for $b_n$, you have one for $a_n$.

Comment: Now results are matching, so I guess I did everything according to your tips.
But I am having some issue in similar reccurence using your method, could you check it out? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090006/solve-the-recurrence-relation-a-n-2a-n-115a-n-28-for-n-geq2-a-0-0

Answer (score 1):

Since for all $n$ we have $$a_n-a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2}=30$$ we have also

$$a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}-6a_{n-3}=30$$

so $$a_n-a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2}=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}-6a_{n-3}$$

and thus we get l.r. :

$$a_n-2a_{n-1}-5a_{n-2}+6a_{n-3}=0$$

and so on...