# Solve the recurrence relation $a_n=2a_{n-1}+15a_{n-2}+8$ for $n\geq2$, $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

My task:
$a_n=2a_{n-1}+15a_{n-2}+8$ for $n\geq2$,  $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$

My solution
$x^{2}-2x-15$

$\Delta=64$

$x1=-3 $

$x2=5$

So I am gonna use following formula:
$a_n=ar^{n}+br^{n}$

$a_n=a*(-3)^{n}+b*5^{n}$

$+8$ is the problem, so I am looking for $c$ that $b_n:=a_n+c\implies b_n=2b_{n-1}+15b_{n-2}$

$$b_n=2(b_{n-1}-c)+15(b_{n-2}-c)+8+c=2b_{n-1}+15b_{n-2}+8-16c$$ I am setting $c=\frac{1}{2}$ so

$$b_n=2b_{n-1}+15b_{n-2}\implies\exists a,\,b:\,b_n=a*(-3)^{n}+b*5^{n}.$$From $b_0=\frac{1}{2},\,b_1=-\frac{1}{2}$, after finding $a,\,b$. Then $a_n=b_n-\frac{1}{2}$.

$$a=\frac{3}{8}$$
$$b=\frac{1}{8}$$
$b_2=\frac{52}{8}$

$a_2=\frac{52}{8}-\frac{1}{2}=6$

Actual $a_2=10, a_3$=43

So $a_2$ from $b_n$ method is not equal to actual $a_n$.

It means I am doing something wrong here, could anyone point out the mistake?

Comment: check your $a,b$ again. Does not hold when $n=1.$

Comment: now your $b_1$ is incorrect.

Comment: @dezdichado how do I find $b_1$ then?
I used method located in comments from this post:(link at the end)   
So I thought $b_1$ is the same as $b_0$ but with '$-$'
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3089757/problem-with-solving-the-recurrence-relation-a-n-a-n-16a-n-230-for-n-ge

Comment: $b_1 = a_1+\frac 12 = \frac 32.$

Comment: I think you should start with a solution that looks like $a r_1^n + b r_2^n + c$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are roots of your characteristic polynomial (which you have already computed).

Answer (score 2):

Define $$b_n:=a_n+c=2(b_{n-1}-c)+15(b_{n-2}-c)+8+c=2b_{n-1}+15b_{n-2}+8-16c.$$Choosing $c=\frac12$, $$b_n=2b_{n-1}+15b_{n-2}\implies\exists a,\,b:\,b_n=a(-3)^n+b5^n.$$You an obtain $a,\,b$ from $b_0=\frac12,\,b_1=\frac{3}{2}$. Then $a_n=b_n-\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a(n) = \gamma^n$ and substituting into the homogeneous

$$
\gamma^n-2\gamma^{n-1}-15\gamma^{n-2}=0\to \gamma^n\left(1-\frac{2}{\gamma}-\frac{15}{\gamma^2}\right)=0
$$

and solving for $\gamma$ we have

$$
a_h(n) = C_1(-3)^n + C_2 5^n
$$

and the particular dictates

$$
a_p(n)-2a_p(n-1)-15a_p(n-2) = 8
$$

so making $a_p(n) = C_0$ and substituting into the particular we have

$$
C_0-2C_0-15C_0 = 8\to C_0 = -\frac 12
$$

and finally

$$
a(n) = a_h(n)+a_p(n) = C_1(-3)^n + C_2 5^n-\frac 12
$$

NOTE

$$
a(0) = C_1+C_2-\frac 12 = 0\\
a(1) = C_1(-3)+C_25-\frac 12 =1
$$

and solving for $C_1, C_2$ gives

$$
a(n) = \frac 18\left(-4+(-3)^n+3 \cdot 5^n\right)
$$

Comment: Does C1=a and C2= b?
If so, I got $$b=\frac{1}{8}$$ and $$a=-\frac{1}{8}$$
If I try to calculate $a_2$ from your last line I get results=$$\frac{30}{8}$$ which is not equal to 10.

Comment: @Gorosso Please. See note attached.

Comment: $$C_1=-C_2+\frac{1}{2}$$
$$3C_2-\frac{3}{2}+5C_2-\frac{1}{2}=1$$
$$8C_2=3$$
$$C_2=\frac{3}{8}$$
$$\frac{1}{8}*(-3)^n+\frac{3}{8}*5^n-\frac{1}{2}$$
Am I doing something wrong here?
Even if I use my version or yours $a_2$ is still not equal to 10